# Check API problme when compiling Android (checkapi-current-timestamp)

Tags: android, compiler-errors, java-6

I got the following error while compiling android source code for the first time on Ubuntu 12.04, I have not chenged the source code at all abd suggested command in error "make update-api" didn't help me

```
repo sync 
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch full-eng
make
```

http://pastebin.com/5gEjkTLV

As the problem is in the java part here is my java installation information. I downloaded jdk-6u39-linux-x64.bin  and run it and copy the file into /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39/ and set the this java as the main java application by :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39/bin/javaws" 1

sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

here is the result:

```
echo $JAVA-HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39/

java -version
java version "1.6.0_39"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

javac 
javac 1.6.0_39
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the dump again. you need to regenerate api/current.txt. You need to run make update-api to regenerate that file. You should be able to build again after that .

```
******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously approved.

To make these errors go away, you have two choices:
1) You can add "@hide" javadoc comments to the methods, etc. listed in the
  errors above.

2) You can update current.txt by executing the following command:
     make update-api

  To submit the revised current.txt to the main Android repository,
    you will need approval.
******************************
```